# counter not indicating as expected 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, counter

my program here should be counting the longest row in my array and which row the longest is on. My counts are stuck at a stand still and my eyes are hurting from trying to find my OBO (off by one) errors. Please help :) Thank you! error in the method `horizontalPath`

```html
public class game {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
         // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER A SINGLE INTEGER: ");
        int n = kbd.nextInt();
        char[][] mazeValue = new char[n+2][n+2];
        System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i++ ){
            for(int j = 0; j< mazeValue[i].length; j++){
                if (i==0 || j==0 || i==n+1 || j == n+1) mazeValue[i][j] = 'X'; 
                else mazeValue[i][j]= kbd.next().charAt(0);
        }
     }
    printMaze(mazeValue);
    horizontalPath(mazeValue,n);
  }
    public static void printMaze(char newArray[][])
    {
        System.out.println("MAZE");
        for(int i = 0; i < newArray.length-2; i ++)
     {
            for (int j = 0; j < newArray[i].length-2; j++)
            {
            System.out.printf("%5c",newArray[i+1][j+1]);
            }
         System.out.printf("\n");
     }
   }
   public static void horizontalPath(char mazeValue[][], int n)
   {
       int[] totalRow = new int[n];
       
       //int horizontalPath=0;
       int count=0;
       int i;
       int j;
       for(i= 0; i<mazeValue.length-2; i++){
           for(j = 0; j<mazeValue[i].length-2; j++){
                if(mazeValue[i][j]== 'O'){
                 count++;
           }
           else{
               if(totalRow[i] < count)
                   totalRow[i]=count;
              count = 0;
           }          
        }
        if(totalRow[i] < count)
                totalRow[i]=count;
        count = 0;
    }
           int biggestRow = totalRow[0];
           //int longestRow=0;
           int finalLongestRow =0;
           for(int x =0; x <n; x++){
               if(biggestRow < totalRow[x]){
                   biggestRow = totalRow[x];
                   finalLongestRow  = x;
            }
       }
       System.out.printf("Longest horizontal path row %d length %d",finalLongestRow+1,biggestRow);

   }
```

Comment: The problem is likely due to incorrect braces. Try formatting your code properly (use a tool) and see if things become clearer...

Comment: Thats really all that is the matter??? I mean I looked through my braces to my logic I feel like they should be fine

Comment: No, but it is a likely source of errors you should exclude before asking... `i = 0; i < mazeValue.length - 2; i++` -> You probably mean i = 1?!

Answer (score 1):

In your main, after `System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");`, in your for-loop, it's waiting for user input, but isn't asking for the path again.  Move `System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");` into your else in that nest for.

---

### Edit

Here is what I have from your code:

```
/**
 * @param args
 *            the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER A SINGLE INTEGER: ");
    int n = kbd.nextInt();
    char[][] mazeValue = new char[n + 1][n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n + 1 || j == n + 1)
                mazeValue[i][j] = 'X';
            else {
                System.out.println("ENTER A PATH: ");
                // You know there are better ways... you are throwing away the entire line -- is that intended?
                mazeValue[i][j] = kbd.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
    }
    printMaze(mazeValue);
    horizontalPath(mazeValue, n);
}

public static void printMaze(char newArray[][]) {
    System.out.println("MAZE");
    for (int i = 1; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < newArray[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%5c", newArray[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");
    }
}

public static void horizontalPath(char mazeValue[][], int n) {
    int[] totalRow = new int[n];

    // int horizontalPath=0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            if (mazeValue[i][j] == 'O') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (totalRow[i - 1] < count)
            totalRow[i - 1] = count;
        count = 0;
    }
    int biggestRow = totalRow[0];
    // int longestRow=0;
    int finalLongestRow = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        if (biggestRow < totalRow[x]) {
            biggestRow = totalRow[x];
            finalLongestRow = x;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Longest horizontal path row %d length %d", finalLongestRow + 1, biggestRow);
}
```

So, some things to note -- we add one to each dimension (x and y). This is because your first row is a border and your first column is a border. Because of this, when iterating, we start at 1 for our i and 1 for our j.

Now, remembering that arrays start at 0, `int[] totalRow = new int[n];`
 is n long starting with index 0.  n was what the user input, but our two-dimensional array is n+1 tall, so that we have a border.  Our totalRow array is a different size because we **don't** include the first row since it was a border.  This means that row *a* in mazeValue is row *a-1* in totalRow.  In order to cross-reference from mazeValue to totalRow, we subtract 1.  Truthfully, though, this second array isn't needed.  All that we need is to track the row with the current highest count.  To do this, we can change horizontalPath to this:

```
public static void horizontalPath(char mazeValue[][], int n) {
    int largestRow = 0;
    int largestCount = 0;

    // int horizontalPath=0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < mazeValue.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < mazeValue[i].length; j++) {
            if (mazeValue[i][j] == 'O') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (largestCount < count) {
            largestCount = count;
            largestRow = i - 1;
        }
        count = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("Longest horizontal path row " + largestRow + " length " + largestCount);
}
```

Note that I fixed a bug that you had in the inner for loop.

Comment: That wouldn't affect that my counter? Atleast I do not see how it would

Comment: That has nothing to do with my horizontalPath method

Comment: You're right about that, but the application is halting, waiting for input, and neither you nor anyone else knows that it's doing as such.  One problem at a time and that is a blocker for helping you.

Comment: (and I would have posted my bit as a comment, but Stack Overflow won't let me comment...)

Comment: A blocker for helping me? what do you mean.

Comment: What I mean is that it was sitting there waiting for me to provide input, but I didn't know (until I threw it in a debugger).  Okay, I've made some headway, but can you explain your +2 and -2?  Why 2?  Also, are you just hunting for the row with the largest number or the row with the greatest total?

Comment: hunting for the row with the largest number or 'O''s and printing out which row that is on as well as the number of 'O''s on that row. The plus n+2 was to print out the array without the boarder of X's and the -2 was simply to get my array to stay in bounds. I have a feeling the -2 is what is killing me. I have lost my mind looking through this.

Comment: Okay -- now I'm getting a little more here.  Let me adjust my answer with some code as a talking point and let's move from there.  This code contains just minor tweaks to your original code, but is more inline with what you want.

Comment: So, some things to note -- we add one to each dimension (x and y).  This is because your first row is a border and your first column is a border.  Because of this, when iterating, we start at 1 for our i and 1 for our j.  We have to 'correct' our position in your totalRow array, as a result, by subtracting 1 any time that we read or write to/from it using values from our two-dimensional array.  We don't do this, though, when we are just iterating over your totalRow array by itself, since we start that from 0.

Comment: Ok you had me up until why we subtract. :/

Comment: Oh, okay.  Let me explain that in the answer.

Comment: I get everything before that makes perfect since, but wouldnt subtracting one just undo adding one?

Comment: ohhhhhh,  the ah ha moment. I can not thank you enough man. You are truly awesome. Most people on here assume you just post your code without trying really hard. That is not the case you helped me a ton thank you thank thank you.

Comment: Check the answer -- I explain it a bit more, but it's a cross-referencing issue.  In short, row 0 in mazeValue is your border, but you didn't include the border in totalRow.  row 1 is your first mazeValue row, which is really row 0 in totalRow (because you didn't add that extra row).  So, if I'm in a for-loop that is tracking on mazeValue (which you do -- the i and j are both referencing rows and columns in mazeValue), then I have to subtract 1 in totalRow to be talking about the same row using i and j.

Comment: Any time :-)  I hope you enjoy school and come out being a stellar professional!

Comment: Hey I was wondering if you would help me with a chunk of code I have been writing all morning for this same program, I can't figure out my logic error(s) It all looks great. If you have any time to help today that would be really awesome, if not not big deal!